# When does the duality functor commute with the wedge power functor?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

When working with modules over a fixed commutative ring, I know that $(M \otimes N)^* \cong M^* \otimes N^*$ provided either $M$ or $N$ is finitely generated projective. Does it follow that

$(\bigwedge^l M)^* \cong \bigwedge^l M^*$

whenever $M$ is finitely generated projective? Also, does anyone happen to have a textbook source for this fact (if it is true)? I've been using Aluffi's algebra text as my go-to reference, but I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere in the book.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer also. I would suggest one of us take a look at how the proof for $(M \otimes N)^* \cong M^* \otimes N^*$ is extended from finite dimensional vector spaces to finitely generated projective modules, and see if the same generalization works for $(\wedge^l M)^* \cong \wedge^l(M^*)$, which is of course true for finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: You should look in Bourbaki's Algebra. There is no algebra text which is more complete than this.